# Find equation for $y$, given equation $2x^2yy'+y^2=2$. Review solution.

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

I need to find euqations for y.
$$
2x^2yy'+y^2=2
$$
So I do this following way:
$$
2x^2yy'=2-y^2
$$
$$
2x^2y\frac{dy}{dx}=2-y^2
$$
$$
(2x^2y)dy=(2-y^2)dx
$$
$$
\frac{2y}{2-y^2}dy=\frac{1}{x^2}dx
$$

And from that I obtain following euqations to solve:
$$
\int\frac{2y}{2-y^2}dy=\int\frac{1}{x^2}dx
$$
Is it correct?

Comment: Absolutely. You should anyway have a closer look at the cases of $x=0$ and $y^2=2$.

Comment: this equation is separable

Comment: Yes, it's correct. Then note that your integral on the left hand side is of the form $$\int dx \frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}$$

Answer (score 0):

solving the integrals above we get $$y(x)=\pm\sqrt{Ce^{1/x}+2}$$